# Indenting bulleted lists in Notebooks

Tags: notebooks

I currently use Word for notes, making nested bulleted lists as I go. I've just started using Mathematica and would like to do the same in its Notebooks, but it doesn't look like it has that capability. There isn't any automatic indenting of the entire line (so when it wraps, it doesn't start at the indent of the bullet point, but it starts at the beginning of the page).

Is an option that turns it on or a module that allows for it?

Comment: Maybe if you post a screen grab of what you are after. Various cell options exist that will allow you do indent and page wrap and so on. Also there is an `Item` and `ItemNumbered` style in the default stylesheet that may be what you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Outline stylesheet is probably a good starting point.

You can create a new notebook by using the **New > Styled Notebook...** menu item. You can also switch an existing notebook using the **Format > Stylesheet > Utility > Outline** menu item.

Then change the environment (**Format > Screen Environment**) from the default `Numbered` to `Bulleted`.

You can increase the level of indentation by typing <kbd>tab</kbd> at the beginning of a cell.  You can decrease the level with <kbd>backspace</kbd>. Using <kbd>return</kbd> will create a new cell with the same level of indentation.

Here's an example (the template notebook is the result of the **New...** approach.)

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing the screen environment? When I try to do a slide show using this method the bullet points go back to numbers.

Comment: @Cam You can use the `Item` styles mentioned by Mike, or by editing (a version of) the stylesheet so that the `Presentation`  environment uses dingbats like `Bulleted`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a slightly more limited approach, that doesn't require changing the stylesheet or environment of the notebook.

The following styles are bulleted, with increasing levels of indentation:

- Subchapter
- Item
- Subitem
- Subsubitem

*Subchapter* is usually accessible via a keyboard shortcut; check **Format > Style** for specifics.

*Item* is automatically used as the style if you start a new cell with the `*` character. Typing the tab key at the beginning of an item cell will increase the indentation (*Item* to *Subitem* and *Subitem* to *Subsubitem*.)  Shift-tab will decrease the indentation.

So there aren't as many levels that you can use with this approach, but it's easier to incorporate into other notebooks.

[image]