# Indenting Bulleted List in Notebooks

Tags: notebooks, output-formatting, formatting

I am writing a paper using Mathematica Notebook and need to create a bulleted list.  I saw this answer ([Indenting bulleted lists in notebooks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/indenting-bulleted-lists-in-notebooks)) and was able to create a new stylized notebook with the bulleted list. I then tried to copy it and move it to my other notebook but the style was lost.

How to transfer this bulleted list into the other notebook?

Comment: I'm voting to close, because I just added another answer to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/indenting-bulleted-lists-in-notebooks/113141#113141 question that might also answer your question. If that doesn't work for you, let us know, and this question can stay open.